# Jupyter Notebooks: How to export a notebook to HTML including the splitcell extension?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook and use the splitcell extension to have two cells next to each other.
I now need to share the notebook with non-python colleagues and would like to do that using HTML. When I download the notebook as HTML though, all splitcells are removed and the cells are unrolled and appear after each other.
Is there a way to keep the split cells next to each other in the final HTML?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The splitcell extension does not have an nbtconvert support, that is, it works just in your browser.

Other exensions in the jupyter_contrib_nbextensions (like toc2) have it; but splitcell does not. Sorry.

Some javascript extensions (that ejecute javascript that makes the output) work with the --to webpdf but you must install some software packages and it still might not work.

Comment: Can you point me towards the a link regarding the option regarding webpdf? I'm not dead-set on html, anything that does not require installing Python/jupyter does the trick....